# we are doing pan OCR, using tesseract but is not able to detect the details like name and pan number

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, tesseract, python-tesseract

We are cropping the pan card image by increasing the height by 20px for every iteration and then we are passing that image to tesseract to do ocr but we are getting noise with output.if you have better solution on Image processing or 
another libraries like cv2 then please help us.

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance, ImageFilter

im = Image.open("image/testpan.jpg")
width = im.size[0]
height = im.size[1]
print('width,height-->',width,height)

yy='img'
zz='.jpg'

x=0
for j in range(x,height):
    img2 = im.crop((0, x, width/2,x+70))
    img2.save(yy+str(j)+zz)

    img = Image.open(yy+str(j)+zz)
    # img = img.convert("L")
    img.save(yy + str(j) + zz)
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(yy+str(j)+zz))
    print('IIIII',j, text)

    x=x+20
    j=x
    if j>height:
        break
```

[image: original image]

Comment: First of all, get your code to identify the region of interest first. Then see how your region of interest look like and what tesseract interpret it as. It is hard to give suggestion like this.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide the cropped image and the corresponding OCR result.

Comment: thank you lamandy for your response, how to identify the region of interst

Comment: consider using opencv (with the text module), it comes with tesseract and you can do text detection and recognition using it.

Comment: A general OCR usually have a few steps:
1) Filter the image to improve contrast and remove noise.
2) Identify the region of interest.
3) Perform recognition on region of interest. You are basically doing (3) right away without any pre-processing and detection. Have you ever seen your crop result? Try to have a look on what they look like and see whether they manage to crop the text properly.

Comment: Added original image, please tell us how to identify the region of interest.

Comment: There are many ways to do things. For your example, you should probably learn how to filter out text (applying contrast, using color range,  edge detection, etc). After you have done that, look into ERFilter under opencv::text, use it to get the region of interest, then pass the region to tesseract for recognition. Also, doing OCR is a very broad topic. You should experiment things yourself and return with specific question after you have done it. There are a lot of details behind each steps and you should look into them yourself if you want to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this ok?

1. convert to gray
2. `threshold`
3. `findContours`
4. `boundingRect`

[image]

Comment: Can you please tell us how to do this things.

Comment: @AlkeshMahajan https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47707200/how-to-improve-the-accuracy-to-get-those-separate-box?noredirect=1#comment82377263_47707200 You two do OCR using tesxxx, and I just do the detect the ROI, I just don't know whether it helps for tesxxx.

Comment: Thanks, We will try this.