# Emgcucv: Gray scale to threshold image not working for OCR

Tags: c#, .net, ocr, tesseract, emgucv

Ok, I agree  I am noob in image processing and OCR. I am having color Pan card which i have to pass to tesseract OCR. I found following thread  [here].

([we are doing pan OCR, using tesseract but is not able to detect the details like name and pan number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47709192/we-are-doing-pan-ocr-using-tesseract-but-is-not-able-to-detect-the-details-like)). I have understood that I may have to perform following steps.

- convert to gray
- threshold
- findContours
- boundingRect

when I am  converting my colored image to gray scale and gray scale image to threshold, my gray scale image getting turn into complete black. 
I played around with parameter but not getting any positive result. 
  So can someone help me on it?

Another thing I want to know whether it is required to convert colored image to gray scale then to threshold for OCR? Or i can directly convert color image to threshold?

I forgot to mentioned that I am using emguCV, Tesseract and Csharp.

[image: Please check image here.]

I have posted  image above and code below.

```
Image<Bgr, byte> imgInput; = new Image<Bgr, byte>(impath);
 Image<Gray, Byte> img2 = imgInput.Convert<Gray, Byte>(); 
Image<Gray, byte> imgout = imgInput.Convert<Gray, byte>().Not().ThresholdBinary(new Gray(50), new Gray(125));
VectorOfVectorOfPoint contours = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint(); 
var blurredImage = imgout.SmoothGaussian(5, 5, 0, 0); 

CvInvoke.AdaptiveThreshold(imgout, imgout, 255, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.AdaptiveThresholdType.GaussianC, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ThresholdType.Binary, 5, 45);
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post some example images and code please?

Comment: updated in question.

Answer (score 0):

I always prefer to use the Cvinvoke method, rather than using the threshold function found within the Image class. You can read the documentation below, but you can use the following code to tweak to your liking. Make sure your image is still in gray scale though.

`CvInvoke.Threshold(img, output, 20, 50, ThresholdType.Binary);`

http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/54f2f6fb-b6dc-b974-16f4-f6b4bbb578d8.htm

If it still looks black, try dilating the threshold image. Although this method wont be needed for your algorithm as a whole, it could help you visualize where your problems are.

http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.2.0/document/html/25f5c3ea-ed93-fcbd-20b7-b046874f8fbe.htm

Comment: Ok. I will do that. After your response what I have concluded  every time it is required to do color to gray scale toThreshold transformation for OCR.